# c# beginners frustration with classes questions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class

i created a winforms application. what it does is it queries a database and displays the data on a chart on the screen.

my question is, is it proper to use classes for this? i know the answer is probably yes, but i have no clue how to use a class for this,.

here is my code. please give me a few pieces of advice on how to turn this into a class if you think that is the right thing to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private DataTable qResults = new DataTable();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string qcvalues_query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM qvalues ORDER by name";
           string analytes_query = "SELECT DISTINCT compound FROM qvalues ORDER by compound";
           string instruments_query = "SELECT DISTINCT instrument FROM batchinfo WHERE instrument <> '' AND instrument is not Null ORDER by instrument";

           dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;

           cbAnalytes.DisplayMember = "name";
           cbAnalytes.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(qcvalues_query);

           cbQCValues.DisplayMember = "compound";
           cbQCValues.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(analytes_query);

           cbInstruments.DisplayMember = "instrument";
           cbInstruments.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(instruments_query);
        }
        private DataSet GetSeriesValues()
        {

            Series ser = this.chart1.Series["Series1"];

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable seriesTable = new DataTable(ser.Name);

            seriesTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("No", typeof(int)));
            seriesTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X", typeof(string)));
            seriesTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Y", typeof(double)));

            for (int count = 0; count < ser.Points.Count; count++)
            {
                DataPoint p = ser.Points[count];
                seriesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { count, p.XValue, p.YValues[0] });
            }

            dataSet.Tables.Add(seriesTable);
            return dataSet;
        }

        private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call Hit Test Method
            HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            // Reset Data Point Attributes
            foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series[0].Points)
            {
                point.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Black;
                point.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
                point.BorderWidth = 1;
            }

            // If a Data Point or a Legend item is selected.
            if
            (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint ||
                result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.LegendItem)

                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Set cursor type 
                        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;


                        // Find selected data point
                        DataPoint point = chart1.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex];

                        // Set End Gradient Color to White
                        point.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;

                        // Set selected hatch style
                        point.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.Percent25;

                        // Increase border width
                        point.BorderWidth = 2;
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            else
            {
                // Set default cursor
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }


        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerSize = 8;

            // Set series members names for the X and Y values
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "datapath";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "finalconc";



            chart1.DataBind();

            // Calculate Mean
            double mean = chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.Mean("Series1");

            // Calculate Median
            double median = chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.Median("Series1");

            // Calculate Standard Deviation from the Variance
            double variance = chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.Variance("Series1", true);
            double standardDeviation = Math.Sqrt(variance);

            // Set Strip line item
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].IntervalOffset = mean - Math.Sqrt(variance);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].StripWidth = 2.0 * Math.Sqrt(variance);

            // Set Strip line item
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[1].IntervalOffset = mean;

            // Set Strip line item
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[2].IntervalOffset = median;

            DataPoint maxValuePoint = chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.FindMaxByValue();
            DataPoint minValuePoint = chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.FindMinByValue();

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxValuePoint.YValues.Max();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minValuePoint.YValues.Min();

            // Refresh Chart
            chart1.Invalidate();

        }

        private DataTable ConnectandReadList(string query)
        {
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            string connection_string = "Data Source=hermes;database=qcvalues; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                var command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
            return ds;
        }


        private void btnGenerateGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string graph_query = @"SELECT top 1000 reporttime,
                    datapath,
                    finalconc, 
                    instrument 
                    FROM batchinfo  
                    JOIN qvalues ON batchinfo.rowid = qvalues.rowid
                    WHERE compound = '" + cbQCValues.Text + "'" +
                    "AND name = '" + cbAnalytes.Text + "'" +
                    "AND batchinfo.instrument = '" + cbInstruments.Text + "'" +
                    "AND batchinfo.reporttime LIKE '10/%/2010%'";


            qResults = ConnectandReadList(graph_query);
            if (qResults.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your query did not return any results!");
                return;
            }

            chart1.DataSource = qResults;
            InitializeChart();


            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = qResults;

        }

        private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call Hit Test Method
            HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows[result.PointIndex].Selected = true;
                dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = result.PointIndex;

            }


        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 selectedRowCount =
        dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            if (selectedRowCount == 1)
            {                                   
                qResults.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                InitializeChart();                          

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: @slaks u should be getting ready for shabbas not wasting time here

Comment: I'll leave this to the big dogs to answer, but the most important question is what will happen to this later?  Is the sole purpose of this program to *display* the information? Then you probably don't need to worry about making this any more object oriented than it already is.  If it might be used for more in the future, though, then you'd do well to consider a little more object orientation in your data.

Comment: If you've never dealt with object-oriented programming before, this takes time to master. I would start with a good book on the subject.

Comment: Are all your recent questions based on you just learning this stuff or are you doing this for a job?  Because using the built-in wizards really increase your productivity.

Comment: @austin im just learning and doing for a job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with slaks on this.  Form1 is a class.

The only real change I would possibly suggest at this point would be to turn that into a composite control.  That way you could drop that functionality onto different forms as necessary.

Check out the [MS walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c316f119.aspx) and a [smaller article here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/13/winforms-user-controls-101.aspx).

You might do that for no other reason than to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

How you organize your code depends on the scale and complexity of your application.

If you are writing a large application you probably want to use different layers to deal with the database, business logic and presentation.

For a small application like yours it is probably simpler to use data binding directly to a database query.

Answer (score 2):

You are already using classes, but not the cleanest, most modular way. It's generally thought a bad idea to combine your data manipulation and business logic in a single UI class. This is why the [MVC composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) was invented, to separate your data, the UI and biz logic into more modular pieces.

[Here's another article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/mvc_intro12122005162329pm/mvc_intro.aspx), C# specific, to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a subjective question...  If it works already, why fix it?

But from another point of view, if this was part of a larger system, I would split it up not just into separate classes, but separate assemblies and namespaces.

You code is correct, for the task at hand.  I would not worry about it right now, unless you are already a proficient programmer (know the syntax) and the goal is to implement good modular system design for a larger scale system.

Comment: @iamagirl: Then What is the size of the project?  You might want to split it up into separate assemblies for data access code and for UI logic.  Maybe even through in a business logic level/layer into the mix. system design is also about more than just splitting stuff into classes.  The classes have to be designed well for their task.  What I am saying is that a SO answer cannot cover all the ground a proper answer requires, this is more stuff that books on the subject address...